# Stack multiple IMPORTXML results into a single array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import multiple seasons' worth of RPG scenario data into a single array and keep hitting roadblocks.

The following formula gets me a series of URLs:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( "https://pathfinderwiki.com/" & QUERY( IMPORTXML( "https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Pathfinder_Society_(second_edition)", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/dl[position()>=2]/dd/div/i/a/@href", "en-US"), "select * where Col1 like '%Year_of%'", 0 ) )
```

With those URLs in column A and the same XPATH query `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[position()>1]` for each in column B, I can pull all five seasons' worth of scenarios using the following formula:

```
={
IMPORTXML(A2, B2, "en-US");
IMPORTXML(A3, B3, "en-US");
IMPORTXML(A4, B4, "en-US");
IMPORTXML(A5, B5, "en-US");
IMPORTXML(A6, B6, "en-US")
}
```

With all the fancy array functions that have been added in the last year, though, there must be a way to pull this dynamically and not have to build an array by hand, right? I keep trying things with MAP and TOROW and WRAPCOLS, or SPLIT, JOIN, and MOD, but I can't figure it out. Am I wasting my time or is there a solution out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do everything in one cell with LET & REDUCE:

```
=arrayformula(let(
urls,"https://pathfinderwiki.com/"&query(importxml("https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Pathfinder_Society_(second_edition)","/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/dl[position()>=2]/dd/div/i/a/@href","en-US"),"select * where Col1 like '%Year_of%'",0),
xpath,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[position()>1]",
reduce(tocol(,1),urls,lambda(acc,arr,vstack(acc,importxml(arr,xpath,"en-US"))))))
```

Comment: Fantastic! Does the job perfectly. Still not used to REDUCE, so it might take me a minute to work out exactly what you've done, but I'll have it in a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,"https://pathfinderwiki.com",
     Λ,unique(importxml(Σ&"/wiki/Pathfinder_Society_(second_edition)","//a/@href[contains(., '/wiki/Year_of')]")),
       reduce(tocol(,1),Λ,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Γ,importhtml(Σ&c,"table",),filter(regexreplace(to_text(Γ),"^\*|\*$",),index(Γ,,1)<>"*PFS#*"))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like it you've got it worked out, too. Sorry I can't mark multiple answers correct. The greek characters are a little hard to use, but a neat approach.